# Linked list loop detection

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

how we can prove that moving fast and slow pointer(from the begining) by 1 makes there meeting point the loop node?I mean i cant understand what gives it a guranteed solution that the meeting node is the loop node(i.e node from where cycle starts)
I am clear with tortoise hare loop detection basically i am talking about detcting the node where cycle starts after loop has been detected.

Comment: This is the [*tortoise and hare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) detection method.

Comment: There is no guarantee - as far as I know - that you will meet in the node where the *cycle* starts. The *tortoise and hare* method however guarantees that you will meet in a node *that is part of the loop*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple proof really. First, you proof that the slow pointer will match the fast pointer after at most n + k steps, where n is the number of links to the start of the cycle, and k is the length of the cycle. And then you proof that they will match again after exactly k further steps.

The point where they meet will be *anywhere* in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to prove this formally, you should first look at an example so you can get a more intuitive understanding of, and can visualize, what is going on. Suppose you have the following linked list, in which the 3 (at index 3) points back to the 1 (at index 1):

```
[0| ]->[1| ]->[2| ]->[3| ]--+
         ^                  |
         |                  |
         |                  |
         +------------------+
```

Walking through the logical progression, you can observe the following when incrementing slow by one position and fast by two:

1. slow = index 0; fast = index 0
2. slow = index 1; fast = index 2
3. slow = index 2; fast = index 1
4. slow = index 3; fast = index 3 (loop exists)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still cant find a mathematical proof behind it.